# File not found when inserting image file into PDF using itext

Tags: java, exception, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

How to add images and design header, footer to pdf using itext?
I have written this ,but getting exception file not found.

```
Image image = Image.getInstance("\resources\image.gif");
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [example](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/20666-Adding-Image-to-Header-and-footer-at-generating-Itext-PDF.html)

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

public class CreatePDF{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
      try{
                Document document=new Document();
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/header-footer.pdf");
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
                document.open();
                Image image1 = Image.getInstance("C:/image1.jpg");
                Image image2 = Image.getInstance("C:/image2.jpg");

                image1.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                image2.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

                PdfContentByte byte1 = writer.getDirectContent();
                PdfTemplate tp1 = byte1.createTemplate(600, 150);
                tp1.addImage(image2);

                PdfContentByte byte2 = writer.getDirectContent();
                PdfTemplate tp2 = byte2.createTemplate(600, 150);
                tp2.addImage(image1);

                byte1.addTemplate(tp1, 0, 715);
                byte2.addTemplate(tp2, 0, 0);

                Phrase phrase1 = new Phrase(byte1 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 7, Font.NORMAL));
                Phrase phrase2 = new Phrase(byte2 + "", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 7, Font.NORMAL));

                HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(phrase1, true);
                HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(phrase2, true);
                document.setHeader(header);
                document.setFooter(footer);
                document.close();
                System.out.println("File is created successfully showing header and footer.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: To O.D, by the way how can i set the picture which is put under project/resources/images/.jpg ?

Comment: wither by using an absolute path starting form your drive name or using relative paths depending on where you start the search from.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code to insert an image from the classpath. Typically useful when you need to include an image that is not accessible from a public url.

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MyImage.jpg"));
```

In my case, I use maven, so I put `MyImage.jpg` in src/main/resources

Comment: my case is similare but I had to use `Image img = Image.getInstance(MyClassName.class.getResource("/check_mark.jpg"));`